# How can I handle weird errors from calculating acos / sin / atan2?

Tags: c++, exception, math, angle

Has anyone seen this weird value while handling sin / cos/ tan / acos.. math stuff?

===THE WEIRD VALUE===

-1.#IND00

=====================

```
void inverse_pos(double x, double y, double& theta_one, double& theta_two)
{
    // Assume that L1 = 350  and L2 = 250


    double B = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    double angle_beta = atan2(y, x);
    double angle_alpha = acos((L2*L2 - B*B - L1*L1) / (-2*B*L1));
    theta_one = angle_beta + angle_alpha;
    theta_two = atan2((y-L1*sin(theta_one)), (x-L1*cos(theta_one)));
}
```

This is the code I was working on.

In a particular condition - like when x & y are 10 & 10,
**this code stores -1.#IND00 into theta_one & theta_two**.

It doesn't look like either characters or numbers :(

Without a doubt, atan2 / acos / stuff are the problems.

But the problem is, **try and catch doesn't work either
cuz those double variables have successfully stored
some values in them**.

Moreover, the **following calculations never complain about it
and never break the program**!

I'm thinking of forcing to use this value somehow and make the entire program crash...
So that I can catch this error..

Except for that idea, I have no idea  **how I should check whether these
theta_one and theta_two variables have stored this crazy values.**

Any good ideas?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Huh? Is it not allowed in C?  - ( I'm more C++ guy. )

Comment: `try` and `catch` are also C++, not C.

Comment: What are your inputs? How are you printing the "weird" value? It looks like that could be a representation of negative infinity.

Comment: So what happens if you use pointers instead?  Still the wrong result?

Comment: Ummm... No luck. Still gets "-1.#IND000000000000"  value..

Comment: Solved! Thank all of you for your comments!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "weird value" is [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (not a number).

The problem is because `(L2*L2 - B*B - L1*L1) / (-2*B*L1) = 6.08112…` is outside of the range [-1, 1] where acos is well-defined for real numbers. So NaN is returned.

Are you sure the formula is correct?

---

If you want to catch an NaN, the NaN needs to be a signaling NaN. For gcc, compile with the `-fsignaling-nans` option.

Comment: Good answer, I've seen this in situations where you might *think* the input value is between -1 and 1 but in fact is the tiniest bit greater than 1 (due to rounding errors). You need to calculate the number first *then* force it into the range before passing it to acos. EG: double xx = (L2*L2...); if (xx >= 1) xx = 0.9999999999; or something like that.

Comment: YOU GUYS ROCK!!! NaN was causing all the troubles!!
I used to see NaN error msg in english and handled it.
But not in this way. Thank all of you guys for your time!